# How can I style a disabled file input button with Bulma?

Tags: css, sass, bulma

Bulma has support for styling a file upload button. The following example has been taken from the [official documentation](https://bulma.io/documentation/form/file/) for version 0.9.3:

```
<div class="file">
  <label class="file-label">
    <input class="file-input" type="file" name="resume">
    <span class="file-cta">
      <span class="file-icon">
        <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
      </span>
      <span class="file-label">
        Choose a file…
      </span>
    </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

How can I style a disabled upload button? I tried putting a `disabled` attribute on the `input` element which avoids the file open dialog from being shown. The upload button still is styled like an active control, though.

Comment: The obvious answer would be: Use CSS. `label.file-label input[disabled]+.file-cta { ... }`

Comment: The interesting thing would be what to put between the curly braces :) When testing with "cursor: not-allowed; opacity: 0.5;" the cursor still shows a hand-index when hovering over some inner areas of the button.

Comment: Then write rules overwriting that. It's probably not a good idea to use a CSS framework without properly learning CSS beforehand.

Comment: My naive self assumed that SO would be a place to aid in learning CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the suggestion from user Connexo, the following CSS allows to render a file upload button in disabled state when the (hidden) input control has the attribute `disabled`:

```
.file-input[disabled] + .file-cta {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.file-cta .file-label {
  cursor: inherit;
}
```

When using color modifiers like `is-primary` on the file upload button the CSS might need to be extended with color settings.

There is a [feature request ticket](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/3291) on the Bulma project GitHub page together with a proposed fix, but it has not been integrated into the main development branch yet.